# What is the most efficient way to change a list to a nested object in php

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a list of (the result of a query in DB) like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "مدادنوکی",
        "url": "/medadnoki"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "جامعه",
        "url": "/commiunity"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "parent_id": "1",
        "title": "درباره ی مدادنوکی",
        "url": "/about"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "parent_id": "1",
        "title": "درباره ی مدادنوکی",
        "url": "/about"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "parent_id": "2",
        "title": "همکاران",
        "url": "/co-worker"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "parent_id": "2",
        "title": "اساتید",
        "url": "/masters"
    }
]
```

But I want to create an object like this:

```
[
                {
                    "title": "مدادنوکی",
                    "url": "/medadnoki",
                    "subs" : [
                        {
                            "title": "درباره مدادنوکی",
                            "url": "/about"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "درباره مدادنوکی",
                            "url": "/about"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "درباره مدادنوکی",
                            "url": "/about"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "درباره مدادنوکی",
                            "url": "/about"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "جامعه",
                    "url": "/soc",
                    "subs" : [
                        {
                            "title": "همکاران",
                            "url": "/co-work"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "اساتید",
                            "url": "/masters"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

I have handled this process with two `foreach` in php and it means I process data twice and it is not efficient and will be slow.
Is there any Idea to doing this with just one `foreach`?
using one `foreach` means faster than two `foreach` twice and It will show the result in big data

Comment: try a `json_decode()` on your result, and let me know if it's good or not for you

Comment: 1 it is unclear what logic is applied to create that second structure and 2.  we need to see your `foreach` loop to be able to offer help...

Comment: @kevinniel That is not the point. Maybe you want to read the question before commenting on it.

Comment: @arkascha yes it is the point, because the first list of your DB result really looks like JSON ! so if it really is, decoding it with json_decode will give you a list of PHP object !

Comment: @kevinniel It is common to use JSON notation to easily demonstrate the structure of existing data. I doubt very much the OP actually has JSON data at hand. But even if... decoding it will result in an array, not an object and that array won't have the structure explained by the OP.

Comment: Yeah quite true you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the results in an order where the parents appear in the results before any children they may have, this should work:

```
$nested = [];
foreach($results as $r) {
  if($r['parent_id'] === null) {
    $nested[$r['id']] = [
      'title' => $r['title'],
      'url'   => $r['url'],
      'subs'  => []
    ];
    continue;
  }
  $nested[$r['parent_id']]['subs'][] = [
    'title' => $r['title'],
    'url'   => $r['url']
  ];
}
$nested = array_values($nested);
```